# Looking for Method to remove items from kanban card divided in several components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a simple kanban app and am having trouble creating a removeCard method

Unfortunately my card components seem to be layered in a weird way which makes it complicated for me to understand where to pass all the required references

I've pasted some code so someone can maybe fiddle with it and understand what might be wrong to advise me.

Thank you very much in advance.

I've tried several existing methods I've found here, but seem to be having a hard time adjusting them to my cards layers.

the problem seems to be between files KanbanBoard.jsx  (method called removeCard and what's being returned) and KanbanCard.jsx and the onClick event on the Delete button

**KanbanBoard**

```
import React from "react";
//import styles from "./KanbanColumn.module.css";
import KanbanColumn from '../KanbanColumn/KanbanColumn';
import SubmitForm from '../Submit/SubmitForm';

/*
 * The Kanban Board React component
 */
class KanbanBoard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = ({

            isLoading: true,
            projects: [],
            draggedOverCol: 0,
            todos: [], 
            text: '', 
        });
        this.handleOnDragEnter = this.handleOnDragEnter.bind(this);
        this.handleOnDragEnd = this.handleOnDragEnd.bind(this);
        this.handleAddCard = this.handleAddCard.bind(this);
        this.removeCard = this.removeCard.bind(this);
        this.columns = [
            {name: 'Planning', stage: 1},
            {name: 'Design', stage: 2},
            {name: 'In Progress', stage: 3},
            {name: 'Testing', stage: 4},
            {name: 'Launch', stage: 5},
        ];
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ projects: this.props.projectList, isLoading: false });
    }

    //this is called when a Kanban card is dragged over a column (called by column)
    handleOnDragEnter(e, stageValue) {
        this.setState({ draggedOverCol: stageValue });
    }

    //this is called when a Kanban card dropped over a column (called by card)
    handleOnDragEnd(e, project) {
        const updatedProjects = this.state.projects.slice(0);
        updatedProjects.find((projectObject) => {return projectObject.name === project.name;}).project_stage = this.state.draggedOverCol;
        this.setState({ projects: updatedProjects });
    }

    handleAddCard(project) {



        let newProject = { 
            name: project.name,
            description: project.description,
            project_stage: project.project_stage
        }


        let currentProjects = this.state.projects;
        currentProjects.push(newProject)
        this.setState({ projects: currentProjects, isLoading: false });
    }


    removeCard (index) {

        const { projects } = this.state;
        const newTodos = projects.filter((projects, i) => i !== index);
        this.setState({ projects: newTodos});

    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (<h3>Loading...</h3>);
        }

        return  (

            <div>
                <div>
                <SubmitForm onAddCard={this.handleAddCard}/>
                </div>

                <div>

                    {this.columns.map((column) => {
                        return (
                            <KanbanColumn

                                name={ column.name }
                                stage={ column.stage }
                                projects={ this.state.projects.filter((project) => {return parseInt(project.project_stage, 10) === column.stage;}) }
                                onDragEnter={ this.handleOnDragEnter }
                                onDragEnd={ this.handleOnDragEnd }
                                removeItem={this.removeItem} 
                                todos={this.state.todos}
                                key={ column.stage }
                            />
                        );
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default KanbanBoard;
```

**KanbanCard**

```
import React from "react";
import styles from "./KanbanCard.module.css";

/*
 * The Kanban Board Card component
 */
class KanbanCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            collapsed: true,
            index: {
                name: this.name,
                description: this.description,
                project_stage: this.project_stage
            },
        };
    }



    render() {



        return (
                <div
                    className="card text-white bg-secondary mb-3"
                    draggable={true}
                    onDragEnd={(e) => {this.props.onDragEnd(e, this.props.project);}}

                >

                    <div className="card-header"><h4>{this.props.project.name}</h4></div>
                        <div className="card-body text-white">
                            <div className="card-title"><strong>Description: </strong></div>
                            {(this.state.collapsed)
                                ? null
                                : (<div className="card-text">{ this.props.project.description }<br/></div>)
                            }
                            <div
                                style={{'width': '100%'}}
                                onClick={(e) => {this.setState({collapsed: !this.state.collapsed});}}
                            >
                                {(this.state.collapsed) ? String.fromCharCode('8757') : String.fromCharCode('8756')}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="card-footer" >
                         <div>
                    <button 
                            className="btn btn-dark" onClick={(e) => {this.props.removeCard(this.props.index);}}>Delete

                    </button>
                    </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
            )
        }



}

export default KanbanCard;
```

Comment: Please include your code here as well.

Comment: apologies as there was an issue with the link I pasted, you should now be able to see it